# Why SOAP requires more bandwidth and more resources than REST?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I am reading many things on `RESTful` web services and I got to know that there is also one protocol called `SOAP`, and `REST` can use different protocols and `SOAP` too. When I searched for the difference in them, I got to know that `SOAP` uses **more bandwidth and more resources** than `REST`. I want to know why does it **need more resources and bandwidth**. Any answers are much appreciated.

Comment: if REST sends XML format then will the bandwidth requirement still be the same or will it change, as same as of SOAP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP needs to communicate information about objects and their states using XML infoset. Typically, these data models are serialized as textual XML.

This, compared to typical REST implementations, consumes significantly more bandwidth.

And SOAP has additional header for every message, while RESTFul services utilizes HTTP header.

So, Avoid the use of SOAP in those situations where bandwidth is very limited.

Comment: if `REST` sends `XML` format then will the bandwidth requirement still be the same or will it change, as same as of `SOAP` ? @Darshan Patel

Comment: No! Not the simple message exchange requires more bandwith, the whole service lookup, stub-generation and invocation (all together) requires more overhead. REST is build on top of HTTP semantics and relies on standardized doucment formats which both are often already available with most web-frameworks/applications. Though, RESTful documents can be more chatty than SOAP messages as true RESTful respones should contain links to support HATEAOS, caching directions and what not. You can also exchange XML via RESTful clients - simple XML processing is therefore a wrong argument!

Comment: SOAP has its limits with streaming as it is intended for simple message exchange via XML payload. Of course data can be base64 encoded and then sent within the body of the SOAP message though there are more convenient ways to achieve streaming. SOAP does not require stub-classes, they are though quite common as implementing SOAP by foot without stubs is quite a bit of code to write. Also, SOAP messages are often (if not always) validated agains a schema - this is what makes SOAP in the end a heavy loaded gun compared to RESTful applications